# Use CGEvent with Qt on Mac Os X

Tags: c++, qt, events, macos

I need to simulate keyPress on my Qt application (I'm on mac Os X 10.6).

I wrote this code:

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
...
CGEventRef mkey = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)46, true);
CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, mkey);
CFRelease(mkey);
...
```

But there is an error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent", referenced from:
      SimuleEvent::PressControl(QString)       in simuleevent.o
  "_CGEventPost", referenced from:
      SimuleEvent::PressControl(QString)       in simuleevent.o
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      SimuleEvent::PressControl(QString)       in simuleevent.o
```

I think I have to link a library but I don't know which ?

Thank you

Nico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your .pro file:

```
LIBS += -framework ApplicationServices
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to link the Application Services framework. For instance,

```
clang -framework ApplicationServices yoursourcefile.c
```

(`-framework` is a linker flag)